# Using Leaflet WMS layer with react to keep changing GeoServer layer with change in parameters

Tags: leaflet, wms, react

How can I use WMS layer of Leaflet with react for this type of logic. Basically I want to update WMS layer with change in parameters.

```
<MapContainer

 <TileLayer attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
 url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"/>
>
<WMSTileLayer 
           
           url="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/PropsureWndb/wms?"
           version="2.20.1"
           opacity={1}
           transparent
           layers={"PropsureWndb:sqlrouteviews"}
           srs="EPSG:4326"
           viewparams= {`lat:${lat};long:${long};lat1:${lat1};long1:${long1}`}
           format="image/png"
          />
</MapContainer>
```